# Change order of constraint listings in Interface Builder's document outline

Tags: xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

Is it possible to change the order of the various top level constraints that show up in the document outline?  The top level constraints are where all the various constraints between my many label elements are and I'd like to organize them into logical groupings to streamline my work flow.  Currently, they are listed in the same order that I added them, however this is not ideal.  While you can drag and reorder individual elements around in the document outline it does not appear that you can reorder constraints.  Is there a work around or simply something I am missing?

Comment: great question ...

Comment: at this point I just hate Apple and Xcode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cannot be done graphically in Interface Builder (tested in XCode 7.3). Also, if you right-click the .storyboard/.xib file and select "Open As -> Source Code", the constraints for your view *can* be reordered by changing the order of the respective XML elements, but once you switch back to Interface Builder, their order will be reverted.

Comment: feels quite hacky to do this and not something i'd want to do again and again

Comment: Right, but it's just good to know the mechanics of how it works!

Comment: My guess is that the order is alphabetical based on the constraint ID, which of course is ridiculous. Sigh.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be a way to do this in XCode 9.3

Comment: I've just encountered a situation where I get one layout when the app just starts, then if I rotate to landscape and back to portrait, I have a different layout. From what I can tell, the only difference is in the order of constraints in the constraints array.

Answer (score 1):

The order should be drag&drop replaceable, perhaps in future versions of Xcode. I still do not see it implemented on Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

The order should be drag&drop replaceable, perhaps in future versions of Xcode. I still do not see it implemented on Xcode 12.4. Shame on Apple.